# not able to update ruby (and also not able to install gems)

Tags: ruby

I am new to ruby.

```
OS: Windows XP 
Ruby Version --ruby 1.8.6 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 287) [i386-mswin32]
```

When I run

```
gem update --system after installing ruby
```

I am getting this error

```
C:\Documents and Settings\abhisheksreepal>gem update --system 
Updating RubyGems 
Updating rubygems-update 
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InstallError) 
    invalid gem format for C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/cache/rubygems-update-1.3.5.gem
```

Comment: Hi, I think i am behind a firewall which is blocking. This is my guess.... Any ideas how to go forward?

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be a corrupted download - Gems has downloaded a bad copy of the rubygems-update package into the cache, and every time that you run the update function it tries to use that cached copy.

Try deleting C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/cache/rubygems-update-1.3.5.gem and trying again.

If that doesn't work, uninstall the version of Ruby that you are using now, and use the Release Candidate of [RubyInstaller](http://www.rubyinstaller.org/). The RubyInstaller supersedes the One-Click Installer, and has a newer version of RubyGems.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response..
I will download and reply back.

Comment: Hi Stuart,
I had downloaded ruby one click installer(release candidate version) "ruby186-27_rc2.exe"
and installed the same file.This RC version was giving me that error.

Comment: Hi,

I have downloaded new file and still the same error is displayed.

Comment: Hi, the latest version is currently rubyinstaller-1.8.6-p383-rc1.exe (under RubyInstaller). The downloads under "One-Click Installer" are now obsolete.